# Centroid Root Locus

Tags: control-theory

I can't figure out how to find the root locus centroid for the poles of this simple equation in a positive feedback system.

$$
H(s)=\frac{s}{s^2+3s+1}
$$

I have read in many places that the centroid is found by this formula:

$$
c=\frac{sum(P)-sum(Z)}{p-z}
$$

The transfer function poles are:
$$
p1=-1.5+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} \\
p2=-1.5-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}
$$

So the centroid should be:

$$
c=\frac{-1.5+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}-1.5-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}-0}{2-1}=-3
$$

However, in this video
https://youtu.be/eyb_RzOnfGY?t=559 , and also Matlab says that the **right answer for the centroid is c=-1.**
What I am doing wrong in the calculation? 
Please!

Comment: I figured out that the break out and break in points can be calculated by N(s)D'(s)-N'(s)D(s)=0, if we assume that H(s)=N(s)/D(s). This equation lead us to s=+1 and -1, which is right. However, the equation for the centroid shouldnt work also?

Comment: A center will appear only with two poles and only one zero.

Answer (score 1):

Centroid is -3. However, since the relative degree of this system is 1 you don't need to compute the centroid, for we know there is only one branch that goes to infinity, and it goes to whether $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ in the real line. What has made you confused about -1 is that this point is one of the breakpoints but not the centroid.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the centroid be at -3?  Ill put it in MATLAB and see what I get (dont have enough rep to add comments) EDIT: This seems right to me, I noticed you only have H(s), do you know if there was any G(s)? I tried to click the link to the video and it wouldn't load, best of luck.

$$ c = \frac{-1.5 + \frac{\sqrt5}{2} -1.5 - \frac{\sqrt5}{2} - 0}{1}$$

$$ c = \frac{-3}{1} = -3$$

[image]
  [image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant -3, I forgot the "-". I will fix it right now :).
As we are dealing with positive feedback you have to make a root locus of -H(s).
>> rlocus(-H);

Thanks for answering.